# Is the eval() function the ideal approach to carry out calculations?

Tags: javascript, forms, eval

I have trying to create a calculator using the eval() function. But for some reason my numbers and operator buttons wont show on the screen(form). Below is my html and js code.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var screenView = document.querySelector('.screen');
const equalBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-equal');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-clear');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.lenght; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    let number = btns[i].getAttribute('data-num');
    screenView.value += number;
  })
}

equalBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let value = eval(screenView.value);
  screenView.value = value;
})

clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  screenView.value = '';
})
```

```html
<section class="calculator">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="screen">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-operators" data-num="/">/</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-operators" data-num="*">*</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-operators" data-num="-">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num=".">.</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-digits" data-num="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-clear btn-digits">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-operators" data-num="+">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn-equal btn-digits">=</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: far from "ideal" ... users can enter nonsense like 4*-+*/...34..23**/ and it'll try to evaluate

Comment: `eval()` is ideal for nothing

Comment: Also, a suggestion: instead of putting event listeners on each button, try using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) pattern

Comment: `btns.lenght` should be `btns.length`.

Comment: probably eval('...') returns infinity or some type of errors. To do a calculator like this, to expand on top what you're doing,  it's better to capture the digits and operators (+/*-) every time the user clicks and append them to a string, then do eval. Be sure to do use 'try catch', when using eval to handle invalid values like divide by zero etc...

Comment: geez! Got to look for those typos. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo there: `lenght` instead of `length`.

Also, I feel obliged to say, that `eval()` should always be considered after everything
else failed, as the last resort.